# Linear Integer Programming: consecutive/adjacent variables constraint

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

Given a set of binary variables $x_{ij} \in X,\ i=0,..,N,\ j=0,..,M$ how do I model an adjacency constraint on $i$'s such that:

1. $\sum_i^N\sum_j^Mx_{ij} = \alpha, \;\text{with }\ 0 < \alpha < N$ and
2. $i_0,\ldots,i_\alpha$ are adjacent/consecutive numbers.

For example, assuming $\alpha=3$, $\{x_{32}=\ x_{49}=\ x_{57}=1\}$ would be a feasible solution while $\{x_{22}=\ x_{49}=\ x_{57}=1\}$ is not because $i=2$ in  $x_{i=2,j=2}$ is not consecutive to $i=4$ in $x_{i=4,j=9}$.

EDIT:

In simpler words given N binary variables $x_{i},x_{i+1},..,x_{i+N}$ exactly $\alpha$ variables can be equal to 1 and they have to be consecutives. For example $\{x_{i} = x_{i+1} = x_{i+2} = 1\}$ is a valid solution while $\{x_{i} = x_{i+1} = x_{i+3} = 1\}$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear to me, but I think you mean there is some $k \in [0, \ldots, N+1-\alpha]$ such that 
$\sum_{j=0}^M x_{ij} = 1$ for $i = k, k+1, \ldots, k+\alpha - 1$
while $\sum_{j=1}^M x_{ij} = 0$ for all other $i$.  You can model this with 
binary variables $t_i$, $i=0 \ldots N+1-\alpha$, and constraints
$$
\eqalign{\sum_{i=0}^{N+1-\alpha} t_i & = 1 \cr
         \sum_{j=0}^M x_{ij} - \sum_{k=\max(0,i+1-\alpha)}^{\min(i,N+1-\alpha)} t_k &= 0
    \text{ for each $ i = 0 \ldots N$}\cr}$$

Comment: Hi, what is not clear exactly? I made some changes maybe now it's better.